# Ember Model vs Content?

Tags: ember.js, model

What are the main differences between the ember model and content?

As far as I can tell, the model is basically the wrapper which contains all the content for the model kind, in addition, it has store related info such as defined fixtures and store state. The content on the other hand, only stores the data with no knowledge of what is or whether it has been saved/delete/loaded. Are there any bigger differences to note between the two?

Answer (score 1):

Are you asking about the `content` versus `model` properties on controllers? They represent the same object. From the `Ember.ControllerMixin`:

```
Ember.ControllerMixin = Ember.Mixin.create(Ember.ActionHandler, {
    ....
    model: Ember.computed.alias('content')
```

Comment: Yes i did mean the controller properties.  Though i don't think they're the same exact thing. They can't be. Logging model and content yield different results.

Comment: @Jaime Looking at your question and your comment you're talking about two different things. In your question you seem to be talking about internals of a record returned from the DataStore because you mention fixtures and store. If you're talking about controller then buuda is correct and you can see the discussion about model vs content here https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/2007